# How do i repeat last sql command executed in sqlite command line?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using android sqlite3 command line tool. How do I repeat the last command that I executed (similar to the / in sqlplus)? 
Tried up arrow and . - both didnt work. I am on Mac :(

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having some problems with the installation of the compiled sqlite3 file (following pktangyue's answer).

Answer (score 2):

I now fall into the same problem.

When I type <kbd>up</kbd>, it prints `^[[A`.

when I type <kbd>left</kbd>, it prints `^[[D`. And it is similar to <kbd>down</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd>

And I found this question( [Sqlite using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414818/sqlite-using-command-line)) and solove it.

First, rename the **sqlite3** to **sqlite3_bak** in android tools to make it disable, or you can directly remove it, if you can make sure you will not use it again.

Second, download the "autoconf" source from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html (second link, currently to http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3071502.tar.gz ):

then cd to the decompressed directory and compile it via the terminal

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Third, put your "new sqlite3 binary" to `/opt/local/bin` directory or set a soft-link to this file. And source your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the last part? Android shell will use sqlite3 file installed in the device/emulator, not the computer, so why copy to /opt/local/bin (device doesn't even has this directory) or update .bash_profile?

Comment: In device it's in /system/xbin, I overwrote this sqlite3 with the compiled executable but for some reason it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

FYI - on my Raspberry Pi 3, not logged in as admin.

Go to https://github.com/robdelacruz/compile-sqlite3 and download the .zip file.

```
$ unzip ~/Downloads/compile-sqlite3-master.zip
$ cd ~/compile-sqlite3-master
$ sudo apt install libreadline-dev libncurses-dev
$ make clean
$ make all
$ make install
$ sqlite3
```

You should be good to go, but if not then check that you're not still running the old executable.

```
$ whereis sqlite3
sqlite3: /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1382624 Mar 11 19:33 /usr/bin/sqlite3
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 4845796 Feb 18 20:23 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
```

If you are still running the old exe then copy the new exe over the old exe or amend your search path so, when you type sqlite3 at the command prompt, the new exe is the one you run. I did the former.

```
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I might have just imagined it and I can't check just now but can you not just press the up arrow key?

Comment: Works on windows. Now I see you are using it on Mac. Sorry can't help you with that.