# How to activate readline on a macports sqlite3 install

Tags: terminal, sqlite, readline, macports

I have `Sqlite3 version 3.16.2` installed on `mac Os Sierra 10.12.6` using `macports`. It does not currently allow me to go through the history of my last `SQL commmands`, when I press `up`, it dispays `^[[A` instead. I do have `readline @7.0.003_1` installed through `macports` as well, but it does not seem to help. I use Sqlite3 in `terminal`.

I have searched the web for this but as far as I can tell, the information I found does not apply to a `macPorts` installation of Sqlite3.

How can I make it work so that I can go through the `history of my last SQL commmands` by pressing the `up arrow`? Thanks.

Comment: Here, you can find that sqlite3 is built without readline: https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/databases/sqlite3/Portfile There does not seem to be a variant that does support readline. Homebrew's version does support readline.

Comment: This answer may provide a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/37639195/1578710

Comment: Thank you for the link Vortexfive, rlwrap worked perfectly. Futhermore, after running `which sqlite3` I noticed I was not even running the sqlite3 install I thought I was. I edited my `.bash_profile` file to make sure the `macports` was at the start of my `$PATH`. Now my sqlite3 works as expected. It was from reading the answers on the link you provided that I managed to figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macports installation of `sqlite3` does support arrow up (and such). You just need to make sure that when you run sqlite3 you are actually running that installation and not an other installation of `sqlite3` from somewhere in your system. One can check that by running the command `which sqlite3`, which should print something like `/opt/local/bin/sqlite3` for a macports installation of sqlite3. If it shows something like `/Users/UserName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/` that means you are not running the macports installation of sqlite3 and than you need to edit your `$PATH` environment variable.